# Pynput with pyinstaller 1.7.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, pynput

I have a pynput error "COMBINING APOSTROPHY" when inputting a single quote into the listener with the international keyboard. I realize most people won't have this problem, but I want to handle that case.

I've looked it up and it seems to be an issue with pynput==1.6.8 and it's fixed in pynput==1.7.0^.

The problem is that I'm using pyinstaller to convert my script into an executable, and I like pyinstaller because it can also make executables for macOS and Linux, but pyinstaller doesn't work with pynput==1.7.0, the latest version it works with is pynput==1.6.8.

When using pynput==1.7.0, the generated `.exe` gives the descriptive error: `Failed to execute script logger`

- Is there a way I can skip the combining apostrophe and not have the whole script crash with pynput==1.6.8?
- Is there a way I can use pynput==1.7.0^ with pyinstaller?
- Are there alternatives to pyinstaller that are better that can still generate executables for other OSs?
- Maybe alternatives to pynput? Although I've had a hard time finding something as simple as pynput

I've been doing `pyinstaller --onefile -w logger.py` to convert my scripts.

The code for my script:

```
def on_press(key):
    global keys, count
    print(f"key = {key}")
    keys.append(key)
    count += 1

    # reset
    if count >= 1:
        count = 0
        write_file(keys)
        keys = []

def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

The error I receive is:

```
Unhandled exception in listener callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 162, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\_win32.py", line 275, in _process
    key = self._event_to_key(msg, vk)
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\_win32.py", line 314, in _event_to_key
    return KeyCode(**self._translate(
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\_base.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.combining = unicodedata.lookup(
KeyError: "undefined character name 'COMBINING APOSTROPHE'"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\logger.py", line 54, in <module>
    listener.join()
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 210, in join
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 702, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 162, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\_win32.py", line 275, in _process
    key = self._event_to_key(msg, vk)
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\_win32.py", line 314, in _event_to_key
    return KeyCode(**self._translate(
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\_base.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.combining = unicodedata.lookup(
KeyError: "undefined character name 'COMBINING APOSTROPHE'"
```

Answer (score 0):

There won't be any way to fix this without updating to a more recent version of pynput. If pyinstaller does not work for this then you will need to use something else. I don't know any linux executable compilers, but you could try dmgbuild for mac.

You could also try an alternative like pyautogui but it does not have all of the same functionalities as pynput. This just seems to be an issue between pyinstaller and pynput and unfortunately I don't see a lot you could do to fix this.